# Alternate path for Remote API servlet in GAE?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets

According to the [Remote API docs for Java](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/remoteapi), the Remote API servlet needs to be mapped to the `/remote_api` URL.

If I map the servlet to a different URL, would it be possible to use the Remote API classes in a client side script? I can't find the javadoc for this, and the examples in the above doc don't cover this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to enable Remote API in your application, you need to add the following in your web.xml file:

```
<servlet>
    <display-name>Remote API Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>RemoteApiServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.google.apphosting.utils.remoteapi.RemoteApiServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RemoteApiServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/remote_api</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

As you see, in the above code snippet the `RemoteApiServlet` is mapped to the `/remote_api` url. However, it is not mandatory to use this url. In the mapping, you could use your own url. For example, you could have:

```
<servlet>
    <display-name>Remote API Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>RemoteApiServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.google.apphosting.utils.remoteapi.RemoteApiServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RemoteApiServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/myurl</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**Update:** Code for the client

In the client, based on the documentation provided at [Configuring Remote API on a Standalone Client](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/remoteapi#Configuring_Remote_API_on_the_Client), you can set the custom path by modifying the `RemoteApiOptions`. For example:

```
RemoteApiOptions options = new RemoteApiOptions()
    .server("your_app_id.appspot.com", 443)
    .credentials(username, password)
    .remoteApiPath(yourpath);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but my question was about the client-side. How do I access the Remote API service when it is not mapped to the `remote_api` path?

Comment: I can't find `remoteApiPath` on the page you linked, and right now I can't play with the code. But I will mark this answer as accepted assuming you are right :)

Comment: You can find that at `RemoteApiOptions` source code, [here](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/java/src/main/com/google/appengine/tools/remoteapi/RemoteApiOptions.java?r=182)